# Matlab - moving data from several cell arrays to one master cell array

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, cell

I have a data set that consists of about 1000 1.5 million line files, each with 6 columns. The files are from approximately 50 weather stations. In theory all stations are time-synched. I have stored data from each of the 50 stations in cell arrays within Matlab. Each station has a cell array of cell arrays corresponding to the files. That is, Station 1 is in cell array #1, and cell array #1 has X cell arrays corresponding to the number of files. Then each of those contains the actual data. 
I'd like to get all of the data into one location with the first column being "time" and the other 50 columns being stations. I don't need all of the data from the 6 columns. Yet.
My strategy is to create a cell array that has a column of all possible times followed by 50 empty columns that the data will be put into. Then I look at each file, find the intersection of times, get the indices from the file and for the new array, and dump the data into the array.

The code that I have for making the transformation is shown below:

```
% One-second time data in datenum format

    times = datenum(2011,11,20,0,0,0:TotalSeconds)';

    % The number of files associated with each station

    AllLengths = cellfun(@length,TotalData);

% Preallocating irradiance cell array

    IrradianceData = cell(length(times),length(AllLengths)+1);

% Loop through the times (November 20, 2011, 00:00:00 to present) and find common times from the data


for ii = 1:length(AllLengths)

    for jj = 1:AllLengths(ii)
         % This finds the indices of the times within the station file
        [~,IdxData,Idxtimes] = intersect(TotalData{ii,1}{jj,1}(:,1),times);

         % This adds the irradiance values to another cell array
         % Can I do this more efficiently?

        for kk = 1:length(Idxtimes)
        IrradianceData{Idxtimes(kk),ii+1} = TotalData{ii,1}{jj,1}(IdxData(kk),5);
        end
    end

end
```

Is there any way to search through the data files, and add the associated data to a cell array in a vectorized fashion? The way it is set up now is pretty slow. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is there a reason `IrradianceData` is a cell and not double?  Changing that might speed things up.

Comment: Are you aware that 1e3 * 1.5e6 * (8 bytes) ~ 11.18 GB? If you have a 64bit OS you might be swapping on disk, which makes thing very slow.
I usually do these type of tasks with my [`Pivot()`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26119-pivotunpivot). If you have station id in first column, then timestamp in second column and one column of measurements, it will form a matrix automatically, and apply some function to the data that falls into the intersection of id and timestamp (sum by default)

Comment: @nhowe - I store all data as cell arrays because the data sets are variable lengths. The data itself stored in doubles. For example: TotalData{1,1}{1,1} is 86012x5 double. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: @Oleg Komarov - The pivot utility looks promising. I anticipate that when I run the full data set in Matlab I'll be in the 30GB range. I have a 64 bit OS with 16GB of memory, so I'll be swapping. I actually tried to create a file, open it for editing, and populate it with data. Turns out that's pretty challenging, though not impossible. I might try that in the future.

Comment: I would actually suggest to store data in a proper DMBS, then perform the selections you need with e.g. SQL and import only the data you need into MATLAB. I often found that many of the simple tasks I was performing with MATLAB on large datasets are easily and quickly accomplished within the database!

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I downloaded PostgreSQL and it certainly looks promising. Cheers.